# FuelPHP: Calling Function of Controller inside Tasks

Tags: cron, fuelphp

I found this document
http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/tasks.html

I created "example" class
Now, I can execute "example"
But I want to change the code of run() function as it can call another funtion
in my controller:

```
fuel\app\classes\controller\user\system.php
```

function name : test()

How can I do?
Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe my understanding was wrong.
I changed to call function from "model" not from "controller".
All I need is just adding "\" before the calling like We call that function in controller.
For example:

```
\Model_System:test()
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not good in design terms to call a controller from a task. If your application has shared logic like that it is better to split this extra functionality out into a model or a regular class.

That said it would be possible to run a controller's action using the `Request` class. http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/request/request.html

Comment: Thank you very much @Uru